# Actionable Message post to Azure Functions or Azure Logic Apps

Tags: office365connectors

If I want my Actionable Message to send a HttpPOST to an Azure Function or Azure logic app, how do I get this working?

I have tried the following two senario's with out any luck:

1. Azure function with Azure Active Directory Authentication. When I call it, I get the following response:

   ```
   {
      "innerErrorCode":"ProviderException",
      "innerErrorMessage":null,
      "authenticationUrl":null,
      "displayMessage":"The action could not be completed."
   }
   ```

This target URL is registered in the Actionable Email Developer Dashboard.

The function is not even triggered, so the error is coming from 
/actions/userid/messages/.../executeAction
call.

2. Azure function with no authentication, I get the following response:

   ```
   {
      "innerErrorCode":"InvalidTargetUrlException",
      "innerErrorMessage":null,
      "authenticationUrl":null,
      "displayMessage":"Target URL 
      'https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/ActionableMessage' is not allowed."
   }
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the actionable message json which you are using to send mail?

you need to have a entry in potential action as a input along with followed action e.g. a options multi select represented as:

```
{
    "@type": "ActionCard",
    "name": "SelectResource",
    "inputs": [
      {
        "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
        "id": "<id_which_will_be_used_for_fetching_value>",
        "isRequired":  true,
        "title": "Pick an option",
        "style": "expanded",
        "choices": $6
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Select one of the resource for booking",
        "target": "your_azure_function_url",
        "body": "{{<id_of_the_input>.value}}" //will be received in function
      }
    ]
  }
```